# C# chart show all labels

Tags: c#

Working on a C# web app, my issue is that only some of the values are appearing on the report (This is the X Axis I'm talking about, it only shows every other value). Its simply showing every other one. How can I show all of them?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

My Code:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart6" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource13" 
                Palette="Chocolate" Width="800px">
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series1" CustomProperties="DrawingStyle=Cylinder" 
                        IsValueShownAsLabel="True" LabelFormat="{C2}" Palette="Chocolate" 
                        XValueMember="StartItem" YValueMembers="STDCOST2">
                    </asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                        <AxisY IsLabelAutoFit="False" TextOrientation="Rotated90" 
                            TitleFont="Verdana, 7pt">
                            <LabelStyle Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 6.75pt" Format="{C2}" />
                        </AxisY>
                        <AxisX IsLabelAutoFit="False" LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize="8" 
                            LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="7" LabelAutoFitStyle="None">
                            <LabelStyle Angle="90" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 6pt" Interval="Auto" 
                                IsEndLabelVisible="False" />
                            <ScaleBreakStyle BreakLineStyle="None" />
                        </AxisX>
                        <AxisX2 IsLabelAutoFit="False" LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize="8" 
                            LabelAutoFitStyle="None">
                            <LabelStyle Angle="45" />
                        </AxisX2>
                        <Area3DStyle Enable3D="True" />
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: In my opinion every value is there...

Comment: Report? C#? Do you mind contextualizing your question (putting your question into a context) in order to make it answerable? And hurry up as close votes are starting to rain. At its current state, I think the answer to your question is actually $6,708.34

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data structure you are using as input to this Chart, i.e., the results of SqlDataSource13??

Comment: ON the X Axis, it only shows every other value, not every value like it should. Thats the question at hand. How do you make the value on the axis show every item within the chart. Has nothing to do with the numbers, just how to show the entire X axis.

Comment: gabriel.  I just got redirected here from a recent upvote.  Was this answer not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 34):

I think some are confusing values with labels.  The original question refers to labels, which are being skipped.

This is a repeat question of [MS Chart with ASP.NET chart type “column” not showing axis x label if there are more than 9 bar in the chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435540/ms-chart-with-asp-net-chart-type-column-not-showing-axis-x-label-if-there-are-m)

The answer is

```
Chart6.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, it has helped me, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Even with `Interval=1` only 1 series is shown. How to show labels of X of all series?